# My shift key toggles running instead of hold to run, how to fix it?

Tags: pc, dark-souls-2

I just discovered when I press my shift key, it toggles running and I need to press it again to stop running, and I can't dodge during the running, I need to double click shift to dodge when I'm not running.
I don't know what is causing this, how can I set back to holding shift to run and single click to dodge?

Comment: I think this falls under either the 'auto-walk' or 'auto-dash' controls, but I am not certain.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.reddit.com/r/DarkSouls2/comments/23x5iz/pc_version_common_problems_and_fixes/

> Stuck blocking/running/walking Constant blocking can be toggled with the ‘lock guard’ keybind.(default m) ‘Auto-walk’(default z) and ‘auto-dash’(default x) toggle walk and sprint, respectively.